# Find out if microSD cardreader supports SDXC

Tags: windows, usb, sd-card

My laptop (Asus Transformer Book TX300CA) has a builtin microSD card reader. Sadly it doesn't say anywhere which versions it supports (SD / SDHC / SDXC). In the Device Manager, it is just listed as "Multiple Card Reader USB Device".

Is there a way to find out what card types the microSD reader supports?

I found out that the USB product ID is 6366. It seems like the corresponding product does not support SDXC, though I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way to find out what card types the microSD reader supports?

According to [Driver & Tools](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/486/0/1/y9ZaV9GlqxM2EVSr/41/), the card reader is a:

> Alcor Multi-Card Reader Driver

And then searching for "Alcor Multi-Card Reader", we can find some information about the [Card Reader Controller](http://www.alcormicro.com/en_content/c_product/matrix-card_reader.php):

> SD specification up to v3.0 (SDXC)

For all of the controller models listed.

So it would appear that SDXC is supported.

Note:

> **SD Extended Capacity (SDXC™) card is an SD™ memory card based on the
>   SDA 3.0 specification.**
>
> SDXC capacities range from 64GB to 2TB
>
> Default Format: exFAT
>
> Because SDXC uses a different file system called exFAT and it works
>   differently than standard SD cards, this new format is NOT backwards
>   compatible with host devices that only take SD (128MB to 2GB) or host
>   devices that only take SDHC (4GB to 32GB). Most host devices built
>   after 2010 should be SDXC compatible.
>
> To ensure compatibility, look for the SDXC logo on cards and host
>   devices (cameras, camcorders, etc.).
>
> NOTE: Internal card readers on laptops from 2008 and prior may NOT
>   support SDXC cards. SDXC cards will work in SDHC compatible readers
>   (not SD readers) if the computer OS supports exFAT. For more
>   information on exFat

Source [SD/SDHC/SDXC Specifications and Compatibility](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2520/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-specifications-and-compatibility)

The Asus Transformer Book TX300CA was released in 2013, so based on the date above (2008) it is very likely that it supports SDXC.

Comment: This can give pretty easily a false positive, because they might not list older products which they don't sell anymore. Also i had a closer look at the USB device (see edit in the question)

Comment: Answer updated.@Butterkekskrumel